# how to generate depreciating battery level using a node in the rule engine

Tags: thingsboard

i need to generate depreciating battery level using a generator or a script node, so that i can mimic the working of a battery .

i need a set of 10 values maybe, where battery depreciates 10% every minute. And when it reaches 10% ,the battery should start charging upto 100%.

can i do this with a rule node in the rule engine?

please help me out with a code for it.

Thank you

i tried this, but it says set interval is not defined.

```
var msg = {batterylevel:100, newbatterylevel:0}; 
var metadata = { data: 40 };
var msgType = "POST_TELEMETRY_REQUEST";

function updatebatterylevel() {
 
    msg.newbatterylevel= msg.batterylevel - 10; // You can adjust the decrement value as needed

    
    msg.newbatterylevel = Math.max(msg.newbatterylevel, 0);
    msg.batterylevel=msg.newbatterylevel;
   
}



updatebatterylevel();
msg.batterylevel=msg.newbatterylevel;
//console.log(msg.batterylevel);

//setInterval(updatebatterylevel,1000);

// Set up the interval for updating battery level
//setInterval(function () {
  //  updateBatteryLevel();

    // Send battery level to ThingsBoard
    // Assuming you have access to ThingsBoard API or MQTT functions to send data

    // Print battery level to console (for testing purposes)
  // console.log("Battery Level:", batteryLevel);
//}, 1000);

return {msg:msg, metadata:metadata, msgType:msgType};`
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of the stateless nature of the rulechain you may need to use attributes as a way of keep track of the state of your loop.

The rule algorithm could be something like this image:

[image]

The key is to play with an index attribute. A green 'Originator Attribute' node will load its value as metadata, an Script node would use it, another Script node would update it and a 'Save Attributes' node will store the new value in the DDBB.

Using script node:

```
var data = [100,90,80,70,60,50,40,30,20,10,0];
var i = parseInt(metadata.ss_index);
return {msg: data[i], metadata: {index:i,dataLength:data.length}, msgType: msgType};
```

Updating script node:

```
var i = parseInt(metadata.index);
var len = parseInt(metadata.dataLength);
var nextIndex = i < len-1 ? i + 1 : 0;
return {msg: msg, metadata: {index:nextIndex}, msgType: msgType};
```

Hope being of help.